# How to create object from QueryDict in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Let's say I got a QueryDict in my POST request, and I'd like to create a new record in database according to this dict.

```
QueryDict: {u'phone': [u'Phone'], u'email': [u'Email'], u'full_name': [u't54'], u'skype': [u'Skype']}
```

Can I do it in one command?
What's the best way to go?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create object from posted JSON?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't have multiple values for the same key, you can do:

```
values = QueryDict.dict()

if values:
    YourModel.objects.create(**values)
```

However, I would **strongly** suggest using a ModelForm to sanitize the data from the post, and then create the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.objects.create(**QueryDict.dict())
```