# using a ModelForm to sanitize post data in Django

Tags: python, django

I've come across [How to create object from QueryDict in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699794/how-to-create-object-from-querydict-in-django) , which answers what I want to do. However I want to sanitize the data. What does the Brandon mean by "using a  ModelForm" to sanitize posted data?

Comment: There's the simplest thing to do on earth to get the answer: google `django using a ModelForm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ModelForm` are very helpful when you want to create just model instances. If you create a form that closely looks like a model then you should go for a model form instead. Here is an example.
Going by the example provided in the Django [website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm).

In your forms.py

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Articels #You need to mention the model name for which you want to create the form
        fields = ['content', 'headline'] #Fields you want your form to display
```

So in the form itself you can sanitize your data as well. There are 2 ways of doing that.
**Way 1:** Using the `clean` function provided by Django using which you can sanitize all your fields in one function.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Articels #You need to mention the model name for which you want to create the form
        fields = ['content', 'headline'] #Fields you want your form to display

    def clean(self):
        # Put your logic here to clean data
```

**Way 2:** Using `clean_fieldname` function using which you can clean your form data for each field separately.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Articels #You need to mention the model name for which you want to create the form
        fields = ['content', 'headline'] #Fields you want your form to display

    def clean_content(self):
        # Put your logic here to clean content

    def clean_headline(self):
        # Put your logic here to clean headline
```

Basically you would use `clean` and `clean_fieldname` methods to validate your form. This is done to raise any error in forms if a wrong input is submitted. Let's assume you want the article's content to have at least 10 characters. You would add this constraint to `clean_content`.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Articels #You need to mention the model name for which you want to create the form
        fields = ['content', 'headline'] #Fields you want your form to display

    def clean_content(self):
        # Get the value entered by user using cleaned_data dictionary
        data_content = self.cleaned_data.get('content')

        # Raise error if length of content is less than 10
        if len(data_content) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Content should be min. 10 characters long")

        return data_content
```

So here's the flow: 
**Step 1**: User open the page say `/home/`, and you show the user a form to add new article.

**Step 2**: User submits the form (content length is less than 10).

**Step 3**: You create an instance of the form using the `POST` data. Like this `form = ArticleForm(request.POST)`.

**Step 4:** Now you call the `is_valid` method on the form to check if its valid.

**Step 5:** Now the `clean_content` comes in play. When you call `is_valid`, it will check if the content entered by user is min. 10 characters or not. If not it will raise an error.

This is how you can validate your form.

Comment: Thank you Aakash. How does cleaning differ from validation?

Comment: Thank you but what I want to do is sanitize the fields so that no injection attacks are possible.

Comment: You can also sanitize the fields in the `clean` function, using Django's filter [striptags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#striptags) and/or [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escape)

Comment: @user61629 - Injection attacks are handled by proper use of the ORM, not by custom sanitization. Sanitization is more for dealing with XSS attacks, which is best handled on output.

Answer (score 1):

What he mean is that with `ModelForm` you can not only create model instance from `QueryDict`, but also do a bunch of validation on data types and it's requirements as for example if value's length correct, if it's required etc. Also you will pass only needed data from `QueryDict` to model instance and not whole request

So typical flow for this is:

```
form = ModelForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponse('blah-blah success message')
else:
    form = ModelForm()
    return HttpResponse('blah-blah error message')
```

And awesome Django docs for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm